# get Facebook user ID with username without graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to know how do web pages like  http://graph.tips/ and 
http://findmyfbid.com/ get user's Facebook ID with Facebook username?

I've have been searching around, the only way I found is using graph API which needs user's permission.

moreover, the user ID from Facebook API is a 17-digit number, but the ID from http://findmyfbid.com/ is a 9-digit number.

Thanks.

Comment: They most likely scrape Facebook which is not allowed

Comment: Actually I've also tried to extract the 9-digit id from the page source of the user's home page with php (the number is able to find in the page source).  but I do not success.

Comment: As I said that is not allowed by Facebook scraping terms. So there is no reason to try